# Electron App is not uninstalling from windows (I've used electron-builder to package it)

Tags: reactjs, windows, electron, electron-builder

I created a sample Electron app and successfully packaged it with electron-builder. However, when I attempt to uninstall the app on Windows, I encounter an `"installer integrity check has failed"` error. How can I resolve this issue?

I'm not getting issue on mac and ubuntu.

can you please help me with this.

[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEPIl.png)

**electron.js**

```
// Module to control the application lifecycle and the native browser window.
const { app, BrowserWindow, protocol } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
 
// Create the native browser window.
function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    // Set the path of an additional "preload" script that can be used to
    // communicate between node-land and browser-land.
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      webSecurity:false
    },
  });
 
  const appURL = app.isPackaged
    ? url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
      })
    : "http://localhost:3000";
  mainWindow.loadURL(appURL);
 
  // Automatically open Chrome's DevTools in development mode.
  if (!app.isPackaged) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }
}
 
function setupLocalFilesNormalizerProxy() {
  protocol.registerHttpProtocol(
    "file",
    (request, callback) => {
      const url = request.url.substr(8);
      callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`) });
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error) console.error("Failed to register protocol");
    },
  );
}
 
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  setupLocalFilesNormalizerProxy();
 
  app.on("activate", function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});
 
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
 

const allowedNavigationDestinations = "https://my-electron-app.com";
app.on("web-contents-created", (event, contents) => {
  contents.on("will-navigate", (event, navigationUrl) => {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(navigationUrl);
 
    if (!allowedNavigationDestinations.includes(parsedUrl.origin)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
 
// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-electron-app",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "author": "test",
  "description": "My fantastic Electron app",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.myapp",
    "productName": "My Electron App",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "public"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "deb"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.80.1",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/three": "^0.155.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "three": "^0.155.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "./public/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:start": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electronmon .\"",
    "electron:package:mac": "yarn build && electron-builder -m -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",
    "electron:package:win": "yarn build && electron-builder -w -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",
    "electron:package:linux": "yarn build && electron-builder -l -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "last 1 electron version",
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 electron version",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^25.4.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.3",
    "electronmon": "^2.0.2",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

I've tried to put
`"deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true` 
in build, restart my machine and many more but still getting this issue.